# Powershell: can't use -pipelinevariable with get-netfirewallrule (dynamic parameters)

Tags: powershell, variables, firewall, pipeline, dynamicparameters

How come I can't use -pipelinevariable with get-netfirewallrule?

```
PS C:\> Get-NetFirewallRule -PipelineVariable myfirewall | Get-NetFirewallPortFilter

Get-NetFirewallRule : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetFirewallRule -PipelineVariable firewall | Get-NetFirewallPortF ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-NetFirewallRule], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Get-NetFirewallRule
```

Comment: https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869/suggestions/11088336

Comment: Also, since the bug is still present in PowerShell Core: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6420